# Subscript out of range when looping through elements of an array

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send emails when I finish my piece of work in Excel.

In some cases I create files to be attached. The number of files varies, but is supposed to never exceed 10.

```vb
Public EmailTo, EmailText, EmailSubject, EmailAttachment() As String

Sub SendEmail()  
Dim EmailApp As Outlook.Application  
Dim EmailItem As Outlook.Mailitem  
Dim EmailTo, EmailText, EmailSubject, EmailAttachment() As String  
Dim EGroupID As Integer  

EGroupID = Range("EmailGroupID")  

Call GenerateEmailTo(EGroupID)  
Call GenerateAttachmentsLink(EGroupID)  
Call GenerateEmailSubjectAndText(EGroupID)  

Set EmailApp = New Outlook.Application  
Set EmailItem = EmailApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  

EmailItem.To = EmailTo  
EmailItem.Subject = EmailSubject  
EmailItem.HTMLBody = EmailText  

ReDim EmailAttchment(AttachmentNum)  
For AttachmentNum = 1 To 10  
    If EmailAttachment(AttachmentNum) <> "" Then EmailItem.Attachments.Add 
    EmailAttachment(AttachmentNum)  
Next  
End Sub
```

When the code reaches last rows with `If` statement an error occurs:

> Subscript out of range

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/396EW.png)

It is referring to the `EmailAttachment(AttachmentNum)` variable.

Comment: use `For AttachmentNum = LBound(EMailAttachment) To Ubound(EMailAttachment)`

Comment: @BigBen , as number of attachments may vary, I define link to each file as a string, using variable dependent on number. So, I can have to attachments needed to add, EmailAttachment(1) will be first string to use, EmailAttachment(2) will be second, EmailAttachment(3) and else ones will be empty and step will be skipped

Comment: @Ike , thank you, that worked. I will check this function and use it in future

Comment: Is this a typo `EmailAttchment(AttachmentNum) ` ? (Attachment)  There is no value for AttachmentNum

Comment: @Blackcat: You are referring to the `ReDim`-line?! That's true: that way anything added to the `EmailAttachment` beforehand will get lost and `EmailAttachment` will be dimmed to 0 with a value of "" for `EmailAttachment(0)`.

Comment: @ike Exactly. And in the If statement `EmailAttachment(1)` is Subscript out of Range.